# Has my post improved?

Tags: discussion

[Why do cross-dressing characters like Hideri Kanzaki usually have high voices?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/56556/45359)

This post received a lot of downvotes.  It seems like the root cause of the downvotes was due to the "voice ranges" section which is rather music theory-based rather than anime-based.  So I had removed the part out.  Is my post properly improved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Has my post improved?

Yes, since the [first edition](https://anime.stackexchange.com/revisions/56556/1) you posted, your question has significantly improved.

The question currently builds a scenario, and asks a concrete, answerable question which could be answered using authoritative sources or prior knowledge in the field of animation/anime.

I would suggest you also take some time to read through [How to write a good question, or improve quality of an existing question?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-to-write-a-good-question-or-improve-quality-of-an-existing-question) to help you on your way with future improvements and questions.

If in the future you are met with another question that is not really well received, instead of [asking why it got downvoted](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4328/downvotes-why-do-cross-dressing-characters-like-hideri-kanzaki-usually-have-hig), editing it, and [asking if it improved](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4329/1458). Just ask a meta question to help you improve the questions instead.

You wouldn't [be the first one](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2441/how-to-improve-my-question-why-is-there-so-much-reluctant-sex-in-hentai) to need help with creating good questions, and the community is most willing to help, if you are willing to put in the effort to improve as well.